# Loop through a list of Ids and perform a dynamic insert statement

Tags: sql-server, loops

I want to loop through a list of country IDs and perform an insert statement for each one.

I need a loop where each country ID is accessible as a variable in the loop that I can concatenate into a dynamic SQL query

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].countryIds(
 CountryId INT IDENTITY(1,1)
)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].countryIds ON
INSERT [dbo].countryIds (CountryId) VALUES (8)
INSERT [dbo].countryIds (CountryId) VALUES (13)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].countryIds OFF

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT CountryId FROM CountryIds)
BEGIN
-- INSERT INTO anotherTable custom sql where country ID = CountryId
END
```

I tried a while exists loop, but this loops infinitely.

***How can I achieve this?***

Answer (score 1):

Try to use cursor instead while exists https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].countryIds(
 CountryId INT IDENTITY(1,1)
)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].countryIds ON
INSERT [dbo].countryIds (CountryId) VALUES (8)
INSERT [dbo].countryIds (CountryId) VALUES (13)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].countryIds OFF

declare @CountryId int

declare country_cursor  cursor for
  select CountryId from CountryIds 

open country_cursor

fetch next from country_cursor
  into @CountryId

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
  --INSERT INTO anotherTable custom sql where country ID = CountryId

  fetch next from country_cursor
    into @CountryId
end

close country_cursor
deallocate country_cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I recommend manual transactions to see if everything goes fine before doing actual commit:

```
BEGIN TRAN;

SQL

ROLLBACK or COMMIT;
```

**Now to your question:**
This should be done via cursor (the following is a simple cursor example)

```
DECLARE @CountryIds int

-- the declaration of the cursor itselfdeclare a cursor
DECLARE cursor_for_insert CURSOR FOR 
SELECT CountryId FROM CountryIds

-- open the cursor and fetch first row into variable
OPEN cursor_for_insert
FETCH NEXT FROM insert_cursor INTO CountryIds 

-- run till there is a row to get
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN

-- do your insert here
-- INSERT INTO anotherTable custom sql where country ID = CountryId

END
-- don't forget to close it an unallocate it otherwise it will be still allocated! 
CLOSE cursor_for_insert
DEALLOCATE cursor_for_insert
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Using loops in SQL is a bad practice, work with multiple rows:

```
INSERT INTO anotherTable (...)
SELECT ...
FROM anotherTable a
INNER JOIN countryIds
WHERE countryID = CountryId
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include an explanation of how your code solves OP's problem. Please note that OP specifically asked about insertion using a loop.

Comment: using loop in sql bad practice

Comment: Don't add comments, this is not a forum - edit your answer instead.